# ComboBox.Change event triggers when other unrelated lists are changed

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am completely new to VBA and I am trying to make a searchable dropdown list "google style". I have managed to do so by copy pasting a simple code I found and later adding some other code to prevent a well-known problem of Excel crashing when using up/down arrow keys to select (it disables them). So far so good...

THE PROBLEM is that while this code is only intended to work for one combobox in one sheet (called Selector), it now keeps poping up when I change any other drop-down list in my workbook - even though these drop-down lists are completely unrelated. When clicking other lists and selecting a value it shows the visuals of the combobox from the other sheet in a random place.

Is there some way to change the code to only make it work for this specific combobox and not mess it up everytime I change other undrelated drop-downs?

Thank you very much for your time and support

```
Private Sub Selector_Change()
Selector.ListFillRange = "MachineList"
Me.Selector.DropDown
End Sub

Private Sub Selector_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As _
MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode = vbKeyDown Then KeyCode = vbNull
If KeyCode = vbKeyUp Then KeyCode = vbNull
End Sub
```